# how to code drivers?

Tags: c, driver, linux-device-driver

I want to code drivers in C in linux os, though I think its very tough.  Can I get some hints as to how to start or books to follow?  Drivers can be from my USB port to graphics card!!

I know as to where I can search for books, I would like to know as to what the basic knowledge I should start with.  Do I need to have hardware knowledge and which specific books are good for novice like me?

Comment: start with not ending every sentence with "!!". ;-)

Answer (score 19):

Start with *[Linux Device Drivers](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=97eyKSX0oCYC&dq=linux+device+drives&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=TFy-cN2dMU&sig=4LgLimN9xuVxX4nBstA9utHlBws&hl=en&ei=GLwvSqeUEM-rjAepzdWTCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2)* by Rubini and Corbet, published by O'Reilly.

It's also available as a [free PDF download](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: Bar none, the only reference required.

Answer (score 7):

["Linux Device Drivers"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005903) (the O'Reilley book) by Rubini and Corbet is the definitive book for Linux Device Drivers.

Cool! see the free pdf version in Roddy's answer & kristina's comment!

Answer (score 5):

try amazon !! there is many books there for drivers . some have samples 2 !!

Comment: Why the downvote? I like how the style matches the question's.

Comment: Because it's not considered *helpful*, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Several texts:

- [Essential Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132396556) (I really enjoyed this one. It has a strong introductory section on Linux and how device drivers generally work.)
- [Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005903) (The "standard" with  a [free pdf link](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) as mentioned by others)
- [Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652) (The longer you spend here, the better you need to really understand the kernel. This will help.)

Answer (score 3):

Before you jump into designing drivers you should first get exceptional C skills and probably some Linux Kernel know-how. Desigining drivers is not trivial and might scare you off if you are not used to programming on a low-level.

I might recommend [The C programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) if you are not accustomed to C as it is, in my opinion, the primer on C if you have some programming background.

Comment: Solid C skills are certainly a good idea, but there's nothing scary about kernel and driver development. The stakes are just higher when you make a mistake. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Drivers differ greatly in complexity depending on the device. USB drivers are on the simple side of the spectrum; GPU drivers are massively complex and even the authors of those drivers usually don't know everything that they do. My recommendation would be focusing on drivers for hardware you personally care about, rather than trying to be a jack-of-all-hardware; it'll be easier in the long run.

Everybody else's answers about documentation sources and various things to read are spot-on and you should really accept one of them.

Many of the more complex driver communities have their own domain-specific information as well. If you want to write a GPU driver, the DRI/DRM and Mesa communities have their own wikis and mailing lists which will help you out greatly, as well as their own documentation. http://dri.freedesktop.org/ is a decent starting place, as is http://wiki.x.org/.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you have here a really good example

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7353

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the source codes of current drivers. I wrote my usb rndis driver by only reading the comments put above the codes.

Get the kernel source and look at /drivers directory. Usb drivers are in usb directory, however usb drivers about networking are resided in /net/usb.

You can learn lots by reading the comments.